# Are @live.co.uk and @live.com the same Microsoft/Windows live/Mail/Outlook.com/SkyDrive account?

Tags: account-management, office-365, outlook.com, onedrive

1. Are @live.co.uk and @live.com the same Microsoft/Windows live account?

   For example:

   - email sent to an address at @live.co.uk arrive in the same mailbox as @live.com ?
   - Do @live.co.uk and @live.com share the same SkyDrive?

   I would prefer if they did share the same account.
2. But if not:

   - I can use either the global/generic top level domain (gTLD - live.com) as the main account
   - and have the country code top level domain (ccTLD - live.co.uk) as a linked account for emails as I think that it is possible to setup Microsoft Web Mail/Hotmail/Outlook.com to fetch mail from other accounts
   - the SkyDrive entitlement with live.co.uk could not be linked to the live.com

Let me know your answer to 1. and your response to my suggestion in 2

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to set up an alias for your email address in the country code top level domain. The option is available somewhere in the mail settings. Here are some steps (note that this is using Outlook online):

1. Log in to your Hotmail/Windows Live account.
2. Click on the gear icon on the top right hand corner and select "More mail settings"
3. In the Options page, click on "Your email accounts" under the "Managing your account" header.
4. In the new page, you will see the "Create an Outlook alias" heading, as shown below:
   [image: Screenshot]
5. Click on that button and you would be able to walk through the creation of an alias in your preferred domain (depending on availability of the email address).

Hope this helps!